# Проблема со сравнением строк

Tags: c, строки

Exe-шник запускается с помощью bat-ника, лежащего с ним в одной папке. Код батника:

```
vernam.exe encode
PAUSE
```

Функция main внутри exe:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] == "encode") // Условие не проходит
    {
        do_something();
    }

    printf("%s", argv[1]); // Выводит "encode"
    printf(argv[1] == "encode" ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"); // Выводит FALSE

    return 0;
}
```

При запуске консоль выводит это:

```
D:\dev\vernam\bin>vernam.exe encode
encodeFALSE
D:\dev\vernam\bin>PAUSE
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: [man 3 strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что указатель `argv[1]` указывает на совсем другой `"encode"`. Результат такого сравнения всегда `false`...

В С/С++ строки, который `char*`, сравнивать надо соответствующими функциями - например, `strcmp`.

Comment: Я изменил строку `printf(argv[1] == "encode" ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");` на `printf(strcmp(argv[1], "encode") ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");`, но это все-равно не помогло...

Comment: А что вы хотите? Вы [описание функции](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) читали? Что она возвращает, когда строки равны?

Comment: @Harry Ответ 5) но вопрос, почему Вы указали strcmp с фразой например ? - если это эталонное решение, которое применяется как в kernel так и в модулях ядра win ?

Comment: @Maggot Потому что, возможно, ему нужно сравнение без учета регистра букв. А может, он организует свою хитрую функцию сравнения. И вообще, в программировании одну и ту же задачу, как правило, можно решить большим количеством способов.